# Render только после получения нескольких моделей

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Я получаю две модели в роутере router.js, как я могу запускать render только после получения двух списков

```
var resourceModel = new ResourceModel()
var imageModel = new ImageModel();
view = this;
imageModel.fetch({
success: function (model) {
    if (view.imageModel) {
        view.imageModel.undelegateEvents();
    }

view.imageModel = new EditorView({
model: model
});

view.imageModel.render();
}


resourceModel.fetch({
success: function (model) {
    if (view.imageModel) {

        view.imageModel.undelegateEvents();
    }
}
view.imageModel.resource = model;
view.imageModel.render();
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью Promise.all попробуй.

```
var resourceModel = new ResourceModel()
var imageModel = new ImageModel();
view = this;

view.imageView = new EditorView({
    model: imageModel
});

view.imageView.undelegateEvents();

var imagePromise = imageModel.fetch();
var resourcePromise = resourceModel.fetch();

Promise.all([imagePromise, resourcePromise])
    .then((response) => {
        view.imageView.model = response[0]; // imageModel
        view.imageView.resource = response[1]; // ResourceModel

        view.imageView.render();
    })
```